# How can I change user document's theme with office.js?

Tags: office-js

How can I change user document's theme with office.js? 
Is there a way to add a certain theme to users' office?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no API that lets you change the document's theme nor add one. I'd be curious to hear about your scenario however. In any cases, feel free to request such API on the [Office Extensibility Platform's UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/83526-office-js).

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: The situation is we want to automaticlly add and choose specific theme for certain type of the document that has certain rules in font and size. So, can you help?

Comment: What application are you targeting? Word? Excel? While neither have an API that allow you to change the document's "theme", they both have APIs that allow you to format some of their elements, which you might be able to use instead depending on your scenario...